# Exim log - has my password been cracked?

Tags: logging, exim

Can someone help me understand this log entry from exim please:

```
2017-03-29 09:12:20 1ct8iI-0001xv-W6 H=(outlook.com) [121.174.171.153] X=TLS1.0:DHE_RSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA1:256 CV=no F=<francofiori@gmail.com> A=login_server:repairs@**REDACTED***.co.uk rejected after DATA: Your FROM must match your authenticated email user
```

The error is being thrown by my acl which checks that my users are only sending email from the address they logged in with. However, the connection didn't come from my user's client (looks like someone pretending to be outlook.com). Does this mean that they have cracked the password, or is this acl somehow being triggered before smtp auth? Is it possible to tell from the log entry?

## Update

Further examining the logs (using eximstats) I found this:

```
Relayed messages
----------------

  1 (outlook.com)[103.16.125.81] repairs@**REDACTED***.co.uk
  => mxs.mail.ru[217.69.139.150] a.v.a_man@mail.ru

2017-03-29 11:20:12 1ctAi3-0002U3-Kd <= repairs@**REDACTED***.co.uk H=(outlook.com) [103.16.125.81] P=esmtpsa X=TLS1.0:DHE_RSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA1:256 CV=no A=login_server:repairs@**REDACTED***.co.uk S=1455 id=DEBCAEFEBFEEBFACFFDAAEECE@**REDACTED***.co.uk
2017-03-29 11:20:20 1ctAi3-0002U3-Kd => a.v.a_man@mail.ru R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp H=mxs.mail.ru [217.69.139.150] X=TLS1.2:RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:128 CV=yes DN="C=RU,ST=RUSSIAN FEDERATION,L=Moscow,O=LLC Mail.Ru,OU=IT,CN=*.mail.ru" C="250 OK id=1ctAi9-0002xM-HW"
2017-03-29 11:20:20 1ctAi3-0002U3-Kd Completed
```

Comment: The acl in question is called at the end of `acl/40_exim4-config_check_data`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the client is somehow using outlook as a relay. Or maybe a virus-scanning service is routing their messages through outlook.com.  Microsoft has a long history of hijacking protocols without regard to the problems and side effects that might affect others.

*Rejecting after DATA* suggests to me this occurs well after the session is authenticated and into sending an actual message.

I would consider updating the message for more clues:

```
message = Your FROM address ( $sender_address , $header_From ) 
must match your authenticated email user ( $authenticated_id ).
```

Comment: Sounds like this is after the user is authenticated to me too. (The `francofiori@gmail.com` email mentioned in the log is nothing to do with my client. I suspect the malicious user was attempting to spam them.) So I can only conclude that somehow they had access to my client's password. I checked the log round about, there were no failed login attempts so it wasn't a brute force. They had the user and pass presumably from another service's breach and they tried the password on my MTA. My client apparently uses their password for multiple services. I have informed them and reset the password.

Comment: The ip resolves to a Korea Telecom listing. I doubt it's really outlook.

Comment: I'm curious what $authenticated_id was.  Maybe they got as far as they did by attempting a local delivery or using your server as an open relay. $authenticated_id might tell us if they actually did authenticate and if so, who they did it as. An empty $authenticated_id might mean they didn't actually authenticate at all.  Consider adding $authenticated_id to the message just in case it happens again in the future.

Comment: Examining the logs (see updated question), they did actually manage to send one email by setting the from to the same address as the login id (which is redacted above). Would that be the same as $authenticated_id?

Comment: Yes. They appear to be the same. I didn't realize that you already had that information